# X100F AF on Single Point

Tags: fujifilm, fujifilm-x100

I just got my X100F for almost a week already and I noticed that during on autofocus (single point) I noticed that the screen is flickering on half press even when I am trying to focus the same subject over and over. Though it does not affect any of the output images produced by the camera but I just want to understand the behavior of the camera because as far as I remember it is not happening on my X70 and X100T.

[Please see video here.](https://youtu.be/Hb9OuiEUn4k)

Answer (score 2):

Recent Fujifilm cameras use a hybrid Phase-Detect and Contrast-Detect AF system. What you are seeing is the Contrast-Detect loop which causes the lens to move back and forth in order to confirm the distance of highest contrast.

If there is a stronger flickering indoors it could be due to the cycling of lights, mostly fluorescent that go on and off at 60 or 50Hz. With a very fast readout, this is much more noticeable than on earlier Fujifilm cameras since each read of the sensor takes a shorter time and catches the flickering.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I also noticed it during outdoors while on f8 to f9 does the hybrid Phase-Detect and Contrast-Detect AF system might be the reason for the said behavior that I am experiencing?

Comment: The Contrast-Detect part of hybrid will cause the lens to go back and forth and a light flickering. Really strong flickering usually happens when light cycles fast, so with artificial lighting.

Comment: After a few links on the Contrast-Detect and Phase-Detect AF, I saw this [article](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/x100f/) and there's a paragraph that I think it supports your answer _The X100F has hybrid AF with the centre portion of the sensor having both phase-detect and TTL contrast-detect, and the outer area surrounding the centre having contrast-detection only. This configuration should provide for a more enjoyable experience with fewer missed (out-of-focus) photographs._